# How to route a site out of Whonix through a normal connection?

Tags: whonix

I have multiple vms running for different programs. On a few of them I have some connections that return a 403 error when connecting through Tor. How can I connect to those sites, while routing the rest of my traffic through Tor?

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet ...

Do you want to route traffic of some VMs through Tor but other VMs not through Tor?
Or do you want to route certain traffic (like a specific program) of a VM through Tor but not the rest of the VMs traffic?

In the first case you just need to change the networking of the VM, which depends somewhat on the system (KVM, Qubes, ...). Just don't attach the Workstation to the Whonix-Gateway network. Instead connect it directly to the host network.

In the second case it depends on the traffic which you want to torify.
If it is some special port which other programs do not use then you can maybe adapt firewall rules so that this traffic does not go over Tor.

Alternatively, if your program supports it, configure the Whonix Gateway to act as an explicit proxy (instead of transparent). Adapt firewall rules and
configure your program to use the proxy. All other traffic won't go over Tor!
You'd also need to do this for all other VMs. Risk of leaks is higher.

Another option, depending on why Tor traffic is blocked and your configuration, is to add another proxy/VPN after Tor.

Or use a mix. Standard Whonix gateway VM for Tor only VMs and another gateway for certain VMs which need partially non torified traffic.

Comment: I want to route one connection from an app in a VM not through Tor. That network the app connects to blocks Tor traffic, but not all of the networks the app connects to blocks Tor. The other solution would be having multiple vms for the app, and that's less than ideal.